# Unique name for a buffer from a base string

Tags: buffers

Having the following function, I would like to use the default name "arktika-N" where N is a number which makes the name unique. Currently it is using the name of the recently used buffer other than the current buffer.

```
(defun arktika-workspace (name)
  "Make a new uniquely named buffer."
  (interactive "B Buffer-Name: ")
  (let ( ($buf (generate-new-buffer name)) )
    (switch-to-buffer $buf)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear to me exactly what you want.

---

If you want a command that *never* prompts the user, and *always* uses `artika` as the "base" name, then I think you simply need:

```lisp
(defun artika-workspace ()
  (interactive)
  (switch-to-buffer (generate-new-buffer "artika")))
```

This will produce buffers named `artika`, `artika<2>`, `artika<3>`, and so on.

(If you dislike that standard Emacs naming convention, and you really want it to be `artika-1`, `artika-2`, `artika-3`, and so on? Then you'll need to write your own equivalent of `generate-new-buffer` and `generate-new-buffer-name`.)

---

Otherwise, the answer by Tobias might be closer to what you want?

## EDIT

Based on your comment, I think you want something like:

```lisp
(defun artika-workspace (&optional base)
  (interactive "sBuffer name: ")
  (switch-to-buffer
   (generate-new-buffer
    (if (string-blank-p base) "artika" base))))
```

The equivalent, using more named intermediate variables, in case you prefer that style:

```lisp
(defun artika-workspace (&optional base)
  (interactive "sBuffer name: ")
  (let* ((name   (if (string-blank-p base) "artika" base))
         (buffer (generate-new-buffer name)))
    (switch-to-buffer buffer)))
```

Comment: I wanted the user to enter a name, but also to default it when the user just hits `return`. Am happy with `artika<N>`. Just wanted to avoid using a recently used buffer that happens to be some programming language buffer that a user might be working on.

Comment: Works well as intended.  The first edit version is straightforward and understandable.  Shall stick with that one.

Answer (score 0):

The argument of the `interactive` form can also be a sexp that evaluates to a list of argument values. In your case that list contains only the value of the NAME argument.

With this form of `interactive` you are completely free in the programming of the prompting for interactive arguments.

The following code is very close to what you want. If you accept unique buffer names with the format `NAME<%d>` instead of `NAME-%d` you can replace `arktika-generate-new-buffer-name` with the built-in `generate-new-buffer-name`.

The function `arktika-workspace` offers a not yet used buffer name as default but it does not enforce the input of non-used buffer names in general.

In theory there could be a racing condition if you have multiple minibuffers. It could be that you start `arktika-workspace` twice and wait for input. In that case the same name is offered in both calls as default.

```el
(cl-defun arktika-generate-new-buffer-name (&optional (name "arktika"))
  "Return a new buffer name based on NAME."
  (if (get-buffer name)
      (let ((n 1)
        real-name)
    (while (get-buffer (setq real-name (format "%s-%d" name n)))
      (cl-incf n))
    real-name)
    name))

(defun arktika-workspace (name)
  "Get buffer NAME.
By default, propose a new uniquely named buffer."
  (interactive (let ((name (arktika-generate-new-buffer-name "arktika")))
         (list
          (read-buffer (format "Buffer name " name) name))))
  (let (($buf (get-buffer-create name)))
    (switch-to-buffer $buf)))
```